# Word 2010 keeps increasing spaces between letters for Heading styles

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

This is driving me crazy. For some reason, my document formatting suddenly changes and I see lots of spaces between individual characters for any text with a Heading 1,2 or 3.

If I toggle the 'bold' state of the text, it reverts to normal..and then again after a few minutes it shows gaps. Is my `Normal.dot` screwed up somehow?
I went to 'modify style' and 'format font' - but there too, the settings are all as default. Character spacing, positioning etc are all set to 'normal' and kerning for fonts is unchecked.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Yes to both..I was editing a set of really large documents at the time with loads of embedded images.

Comment: No, I hadn't tried that before! I don't have any other large documents now to test out (that was while at work, and I no longer work there or use Word that extensively at my current job) but will keep this in mind next time, thanks!